# Setting @ManyToOne or @OneToOne relationship without actually fetching the associated entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have entity similiar to

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Template")
public class Template implements java.io.Serializable {
      Script script;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "SCRIPTID")
      public Script getScript() {
          return script;
      }

      public void setScript(Script script) {
          this.script= script;
      }
}
```

where `Script` is another entity.

When I want to save `Template`, I get id of `Script`from some legacy code so my saving code is:

```
 Long scriptId = createNewScript(....);
 Script script = commonDao.findByPrimaryKey(Script.class, scriptId); //unnecessary reading
 template.setScript(script);

 commonDao.save(template);
```

The problem is that I have to do unnecessary read the `Script` only to set it in `Template`. Is there any way to set only Id of script, but still have getter that returns `Script`.

Comment: I don't think if there is, because template.getScript(); will return the script only if the script is in persistent state or exists in database or you have setted it without persisting it to database I mean: template.setScript(script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Hibernate allows you to do something like this:

```
template.setScript(new Script());
template.getSCript().setId(scriptId);
commonDao.save(template);
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, can you please take a look at my post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080681/how-to-configure-enhanced-tablegenerator-in-hibernate